# Command substitution- invalid command code $

Tags: bash, sed

Can you see what goes wrong in the following:

```
sed -i '' "1h; 1 $ { x; s/CHANGE_THIS/$TMP/; p; }" .zshrc_
```

error:

```
sed: 1: "1h; 1 $ { x; s/CHANGE_T ...": invalid command code $
```

Comment: To do something on every line, you don't have to add an address. `1,$ {cmd; cmd}` is the same as `cmd; cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for address range is `addr1,addr2`, not `addr1 addr2`. The range's missing a comma:

```
sed -i '' "1h; 1,$ { x; s/CHANGE_THIS/$TMP/; p; }" .zshrc_
```

Comment: Thanks, no error but now it changes strange things - I was trying to change first occurrence of a string

Comment: Try asking a new question, there's no mention of what you need in this one.